# Downloading/storing Periscope live streaming broadcasts

Tags: javascript, twitter, download, video-streaming, live-streaming

I'm crawling tweets and, if available, store information to external resources (e.g., Instagram images). Now poeple start using Periscope where users tweet links to a Periscope live streaming broadcast (also then available for the next 24h). [Here](https://www.periscope.tv/w/VysPPjEzODk3NTZ8OTUxMDA2NpBSD8LFCooHM_t2Z-iSI0h00Hi0CuPMht8ywK1834dj) is an example link, but it might be invalid/obsolete soon.

Is there any way I can fetch that broadcast, i.e., store it locally as a video file?

When I look at the source code of a Periscope broadcast, I get something like that:

```
<html>
<head>
  ...
  <script src="https://assets.periscope.tv/assets/bugsnag-2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://assets.periscope.tv/js/vendor.a8cd99eb89a488ec6ea465f57d3ad41bcd832eff.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="periscope-app" class="u-fullHeight"></div>
  <script src="https://assets.periscope.tv/js/application.min.2a8176c317fb715fd0e6c2728cb04318c5c53941.js"></script>
</body>
```

So everything is essentially scripted. I've tried to look into the Javascript file to see if I can somehow at least reconstruct the stream URL or something. But I wasn't successful. I also tried with Google Chrome to inspect the requests made from the side. But this also didn't bring me any further.

EDIT: Here's my current Phantom.js script:

```
var page = require('webpage').create(),
  system = require('system'),
  t, address;

if (system.args.length === 1) {
  console.log('Usage: periscope.js <periscope-url>');
  phantom.exit();
}

page.onResourceRequested = function(request) {
  console.log('Request ' + JSON.stringify(request, undefined, 4));
};

page.onResourceReceived = function(response) {
  console.log('Receive ' + JSON.stringify(response, undefined, 4));
};

address = system.args[1];

page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.71 Safari/537.36';
page.open(address, function(status) {
  if (status !== 'success') {
    console.log('FAIL to load the address');
  } else {

  }
  //phantom.exit();
});
```

When I use Google Chrome's Developer Tools I find the `application/vnd.apple.mpegurl` request, but it never pops up from the Phantom.js script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It uses Http Live Streaming (HLS) on Chrome Desktop so just proxy/sniff HTTP responses of type `application/vnd.apple.mpegurl` and get the request URL. I was able to watch your stream in VLC.

You can use [Phantom.js](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-requested.html).

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I've managed to reproduce that. I also tried various ways to store the stream (`vlc`, `ffmpeg`, `hls-fetch`). With `vlc` and `ffmpeg` I didn't get good results - no sound, wrong playback speed, errors. The results of the `hls-fetch` Perl script are perfect. The only thing is that it stops after 3 segments, but I might be able to extend the script myself. Anyway, I have no idea how I can extract the URL of the stream in a programmatic manner.

Comment: You're using the `playlist.m3u8` URL, right? It works in VLC 2.x just fine. Like I said above, to get it  in code intercept the requests. You can do it with Phantom.js. I updated the answer with a link to the docs.

Comment: I marked you answer as correct since it comes pretty close to what I am looking for - haven't really looked at Phantom.js though. Anyone, the bottom line seems to be that it is not as straightforward as I hoped for :).

Comment: I installed and played around with Phantom.js. I tried different examples that basically sniff and log the HTTP request and responses. However, I simply cannot find the `application/vnd.apple.mpegurl` among all the requests -- which I do find using Google Chrome's Developer Console, for example. What am I missing? I would guess that the HTTP response I get include some Javascript code which make additional HTTP request that Phantom.js no longer covers. But I have no idea reall.

Comment: You probably need to override the user agent so it "detects" your device's capabilities

Comment: I included the code of my Phantom.js script to my question. It now also includes now a line where I set the user agent. Since I have no idea how to choose the "right" agent, I used an example I found online. No change, unfortunately.

Comment: Try to output the page, maybe it doesn't require the video at all. Otherwise you might need to go to a lower level like capture the actual traffic.

Answer (score 2):

the latest version of the fantastic [livestreamer](https://github.com/chrippa/livestreamer) (1.12.2) can download periscope videos

```
livestreamer https://www.periscope.tv/w/aKzPpDIxNDYxN3w2OTg1MTQxNZnjGACxw2Nyl6RSvdnX8T3EaE7z5mSvxfK_-uqS5SQv best --output output.mp4
```

if you want to do it programmatically seeing as this is StackOverflow, the periscope plugin in python is here:
https://github.com/chrippa/livestreamer/blob/develop/src/livestreamer/plugins/periscope.py

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but apparently it's not working anymore after they are using `playlist.m3u8`. I managed to download using [Scopedown](http://downloadperiscopevideos.com/) and then you have a TS file (*need proper codecs*).